# Delete a selected row from list boxes in Userform

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have two list boxes in my Userform. The first one is lstBox1 and the other lstBox2 with sheets "PUB1" and "PUB2" respectively. I tried creating a command button that can delete a selected row from any of the list boxes as well as in the sheet and shift up the cell row so that there won't be a blank row.

I used the following lines of code to initiate it for one of the listboxes and it worked perfectly but don't know how to modify it to work for the other listbox under the same procedure.

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()

Dim i As Integer

For i=0 To Range ("A50").End(x1Up).Row-1

 If lstBox1.Selected(i) Then

   Rows(i).Select

   Selection.Delete

  End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Your constant should be `xlUp` not `x1Up`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Something like this:**

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()

With Worksheets("PUB1")
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To .Range("A50").End(xlUp).row

 If lstBox1.Selected(i) Then

   .Rows(i).Delete

 End If

Next i
End With

With Worksheets("PUB2")

For i = 1 To .Range("A50").End(xlUp).row

 If lstBox1.Selected(i) Then

   .Rows(i).Delete

 End If

Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Friendly hint:-) missing `End With`s; generally and despite the low row counter <50 I'd prefer a type declaration of `i As Long` instead of `Integer` for sheet counters (in order to avoid a possible overflow).

Comment: @T.M. .. Thanks for Spotting that. :)

Comment: The code gives error whenever I click the Delete Button.

Comment: Which line gives the Error ?

Comment: The whole code starting from the third line. I even tried removing the dot(.) before Range but didn't respond to the command.

Comment: @wallevic , The only thing that i saw problematic was the loop from 0, as Row(0) does not exist, I changed it. Try again and let me know.

Comment: After trying the code, I received an error message which says "Runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: Also, when I tried the code only with PUB1, it deleted the row before the one I clicked on.

Comment: It is not visible in the question, what you have in the List Box. So if a previous row is being deleted , you can try `.Rows(i+1).Delete
`

Comment: @Mikku Thank you for your time and help. I've got a solution to it, had to change the code completely to another I found online. I also think your code is right because at first when I entered it, I got a result though with some errors which I believe are due to some of my codes thereby conflicting themselves.

Comment: I might still be in need of your help later. Thanks